# What's the difference between uIP, lwIP, 6LoWPAN?

Tags: sensor, wireless, network

I just started to work on a wireless sensor network project and encounter these three terms: uIP, lwIP, 6LoWPAN.  Since I'm new to this area, could anyone please explain the differences between these three terms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[uIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIP_%28micro_IP%29) and [lwIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LwIP) are both open source TCP/IP stacks used for embedded/microcontroller systems.

[6LoWPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN) is a network protocol which works over the [IEEE 802.15.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) wireless layer.